# Method rxExecuteBlocking consuming all results - ssh client

Tags: java, ssh, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to do really simple SSH client with Vert.x. As I don't have non-blocking SSH library under the hood, I have to handle everything in `rxExecuteBlocking`. It's working great when I'm running all logic in one big block of code as follows:

```
public Single<String> exec() {
   return vertx.rxExecuteBlocking(f -> {
       String result = "";

       // connect()
       // exec()
       // close()

       f.complete(result);
   }, false);
}

// hostnames :: Observalbe<String>
hostnames()
  .filter()
  .flatMapSingle(this::exec)
  .moreCalls()
  .subscribe(); // OK
```

I'd rather to have `connect()`, `exec()`, `close()` separeted and call like:

```
hostnames()
  .filter()
  .flatMapSingle(this::connect)
  .moreCalls()
  .flatMapSingle(this::exec)
  .moreCalls()
  .flatMapSingle(this::close)
  .subscribe();
```

But when running more than one piece of blocking code

```
public Single<Connection> connect() {
  return vertx.rxExecuteBlocking(f -> {
     // connect
  }, false);
}

public Single<Connection> exec() {
  return vertx.rxExecuteBlocking(f -> {
     // exec
  }, false);
}
```

the chain stops at `flatMapSingle(this::connect)`, consume all results from `filter()` first (make all connections) and then continue in chain. This behavior consumes pretty much resources as all connections are in memory (this behavior reminds me `reduce()` or `collect()`)

The desired result will be not stopping in chain and continue, release resources and do this for every event.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like yours worker pool size (default is 20) is close to connections count, so it's expected, that multiple parallel `connect` consumes all available threads and chain not continue until some thread is released

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Good point, I've tried increase pool size and not using too many connections, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to use overloaded `flatMap`, which takes as an argument the maximum number of concurrently subscribed observables at the particular pipeline stage. Provided there are 20 threads in worker thread pool by default, you could give a fraction of the pool to each of `flatMap` calls, e.g. 5 to each.

```
hostnames()
  // ...some filtering
  .flatMap(hostname -> this.connect(hostname).toObservable(), 5)
  // ...more operators
  .flatMap(connection -> this.exec(connection).toObservable(), 5)
  // ...more operators
  .flatMap(connection -> this.close(connection).toObservable(), 5)
  .subscribe();
```

This will ensure that not the whole thread pool is used at the same moment.

Some tweaks to concurrent load may be needed. For example, less concurrently subscribed observables for `connect` and more for `exec` if `connect` is faster than `exec`. Thus, results of `connect` are not stacked in a buffer before `exec`.